# javascript getProperty

Tags: javascript, object, key-value-coding, getproperty

I'm a complete beginner trying to learn Javascript. I am trying to complete a problem requiring me to return a *value* assigned to a *key*. The function is called *getProperty* and I am stuck - it keeps returning "should return the value of the property located in the object at the passed in key" every time I attempt to run a test on the code.

```
    var obj = {key: 'value'};

    function getProperty(obj, key) {
        var o = obj.key;
        return(o);
    }

    console.log(getProperty);
```

Comment: please make your description really short what is actually neded to answer the question. most of the people skips if there is a long description.

Comment: point taken into consideration for the next time I have a question

Answer (score 5):

For dynamic attribute names you need to use the bracket `[]` notation instead of the dot notation:

```
var o = obj[key];
return o
```

Thanks to @Gaby for pointing out that you also need to call the function with valid arguments:

```
console.log(getProperty(obj, 'key'));
```

Comment: and to log it they need to actually call the method `console.log(getProperty(obj,'key'));`

Answer (score 1):

The "key" parameter for the method is irrelevant since you are not using it anywhere in the method. Also, the method needs the obj parameter when you call it.

```
   var obj = {key: 'value'};

    function getProperty(obj) {
        var o = obj.key;
        return(o);
    }

    console.log(getProperty(obj));
```